# Show that $\angle PCX=45$. if and only if $\angle (CP,YN)=30$

Tags: geometry, angle

**the question**

Consider the regular quadrilateral pyramid $VABCD$ with the vertex in $V$ and the points $M, N, P$ the means of the segments $AD, BC, VA$. Show that the angle of the line $CP$ with the plane $(BAD)$ has a measure of $45$ if and only if the angle of the line $CP$ with the plane $(VMN)$ has a measure of $30$.

**The idea**

**The drawing**

[image]

First, let's clarify the angles between the lines and the planes.

$1)$ $\angle(CP,(BAD))$

Let $PX \perp (BAD)$ and we know that $C\in(BAD)=> \angle(CP,(BAD))=\angle PCX$

Also, we can demonstrate that X is the midpoint of AO.

$2)$ $\angle(CP,(VMN))$

Let $PY \perp (VMN)$ and we know that $CN \perp (VMN)=> \angle(CP,(VMN))= \angle (CP,YN)$

We can simply show that Y is the midpoint of line VM

$YP||CN$ and $CN>PY$ so that means that $PYCN$ is a trapeze.

Let $BC=4l$

From now we have two cases:

case_1: We know that $\angle PCX=45$. we show that $\angle (CP,YN)=30$

case_2: We show that $\angle PCX=45$. we know that $\angle (CP,YN)=30$

case_1:

$\angle PCX=45$ means that traingle $PXC$ is right angled and issoscels $=> PX=XC=3l\sqrt{2}=> PC=6l$

Let $YZ \perp (ABCD)$ and $ZN=3l, PX=YZ=3l\sqrt{2}$

From here we get that $YN$ doesn't equal $PC$ so the trapezoid PYCN isn't isosceles.

I don't know what to do forward. I hope one fo you can help me!

Comment: HINT. The angle between line $$ with plane $()$ is $\angle CQN$, where $Q$ is the intersection between $CP$ and $VO$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thank you so much for yur idea, but I dont understand how is this going to help and how you arrived to this conclusion...

Comment: From $\angle CQN=30°$ you can find $VO/AB=3/\sqrt2$. And you get the same ratio from $\angle PCX=45°$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca May i ask you how you got to the conclusion that $\angle CQN$ is the angle between that line and plane...All I k=can see is that $Q$ is the centroid of $VAC$

Comment: Because $N$ is the projection of $C$ on plane $VMN$.